# I am writing a code to perform polynomial addition and multiplication using linked list.I have a problem

Tags: c

In my code the addition part is working. But the multiplication part is not working.. The problem is in create_node() function... and the loop to multiply 2 polynomials.
THE CODE IS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int cof;
    int exp;
    struct node* next; 
}*phead ,*rt, *qhead , *rhead,*newh,*ph,*qh,*rh;

void create_node(struct node* header)
{
    int degree,c,i;
    header->next=NULL;
    struct node* ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    printf("Enter the degree of the polynomial:");
    scanf("%d",&degree);
    for(i=degree; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("Enter the coficient of x^%d:",i);
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if(c!=0)
        {
            struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
            newnode->cof = c;
            newnode->exp = i;
            if(header->next==NULL)
            {
                header->next = newnode;
                ptr=newnode;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr->next=newnode;
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    ptr->next=NULL;

}

void display()
{
    struct node *pptr,*qptr,*rptr;
    pptr=phead->next;
    qptr=qhead->next;
    rptr=rhead->next;

    printf("\nThe entered polynomials are:");
    printf("\npolynomial 1:");
    while(pptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",pptr->cof,pptr->exp);
        pptr = pptr->next;
    }
    printf("\npolynomial 2:");
    while(qptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",qptr->cof,qptr->exp);
        qptr = qptr->next;
    }

    printf("\nThe resultant  polynomial is:");
    while(rptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",rptr->cof,rptr->exp);
        rptr = rptr->next;
    }
}

void displayp()
{
    struct node *p1,*q1,*r1;
    p1=ph->next;
    q1=qh->next;
    r1=rh;

    printf("\nThe entered polynomials are:");
    printf("\npolynomial 1:");
    while(p1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",p1->cof,p1->exp);
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    printf("\npolynomial 2:");
    while(q1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",q1->cof,q1->exp);
        q1 = q1->next;
    }

    printf("\nThe resultant  polynomial is:");
    while(r1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d + ",r1->cof,r1->exp);
        r1 = r1->next;
    }
}
void main()
{
    struct node *pptr , *qptr , *rptr,*pn,*pn1,*x,*pt,* qt,*rt;
    phead = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    qhead = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    rhead = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    pn = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    pn1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    create_node(phead);
    create_node(qhead);



    pptr = phead;
    qptr = qhead;
    rptr = rhead;
    x = rhead;
    while (pptr!=NULL && qptr!=NULL)
    {
        newh = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (pptr->exp == qptr->exp)
        {
            newh->cof = pptr->cof + qptr->cof;
            newh->exp = pptr->exp; 
            pptr = pptr->next;
            qptr = qptr->next;
        }

        else if (pptr->exp>qptr->exp)
        {

            newh->cof = pptr->cof;
            newh->exp = pptr->exp;
            pptr = pptr->next;
        }

        else if (pptr->exp<qptr->exp)
        {
            newh->cof = qptr->cof;
            newh->exp = qptr->exp;
            qptr = qptr->next;
        }
        if (rhead == NULL)
        {
            rhead = newh;
            rptr = newh;
        }
        else
        {
            rptr->next = newh;
            rptr = newh;
        }
    }
    while (pptr!=NULL)
    {
        newh = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newh->cof = pptr->cof;
        newh->exp = pptr->exp;
        newh->next = NULL;
        rptr->next = newh;
        rptr = newh;
        pptr = pptr->next;
    }
    while (qptr!=NULL)
    {
        newh = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newh->cof = qptr->cof;
        newh->exp = qptr->exp;
        newh->next = NULL;
        rptr->next = newh;
        rptr = newh;
        qptr = qptr->next;
    }
    display();
               printf("---------------------------------------\n");
         printf("POLYNOMIAL MULTIPLICATION\n");
         ph = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         qh = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         rt = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         create_node(ph);
         create_node(qh);
 //      displayp();
         printf("\n");
         pt = ph->next;
         qt = qh->next;
         rh = NULL;
         //rt = rh;
         while (pt!=NULL)
         {
                 while (qt!=NULL)
                 {
                         if (rh == NULL)
                         {
                                 rt->cof = pt->cof * qt->cof;
                                 rt->exp = pt->exp + qt->exp;
                                 rh = rt;
                                //pt = pt->next;
                                              //rt->next = NULL;
                                 qt = qt->next;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                                 struct node *nw = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                                 nw->cof = pt->cof * qt->cof;
                                 nw->exp = pt->exp + qt->exp;
                                 //nw->next = NULL;
                                 rt->next = nw;
                                 rt = rt->next;
                                 qt = qt->next;
                         }
                 }
         //       displayp();
                 pt = pt->next;

         }

         displayp();
 }
```

Ok ill get to the point. In the multiplication loop the first node is being multiplied to all the other nodes in 2nd polynomial. Then the execution stops.
pt = pt->next is not being executed.

Please help

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. I also suggest you [try to find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/), and [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Are you actually creating and linking new nodes with respect to the header node?  It looks like you might be assigning new values to the same next-node, then in main advancing to that same node in the assignment of pt (pt = pt -> next),  leaving you with one iteration.

Comment: I strongly recommend that as a first step, write a small set of routines to manage a linked list: initialize, insert node, delete node, iterate over.  Google to find an example, no doubt there are many.  Then use that API in your polynomial manipulation code.  Far too many bugs are caused by mixing data structure management with "business logic" (in your case, math logic.)  Keep them separate.